# Prettier is not indenting as specified

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier continues to format my code incorrectly. I desire 4 spaces for tabs (second picture) but it ignores the editor settings and does 2 (first picture).

I know it is prettier causing this because when I disable it vs code correctly indents for me. Unfortunately the other functionality of prettier is lost. I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

So, what settings changes am I missing? I must be missing something. Any suggestions would be grand. Thanks.

Here are are all of prettier's settings I have changed.

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true
```

[image: incorrect]

[image: correct]

Comment: in vscode settings.json add this line `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Are you using .editorconfig? You might have to change (or set) to

```
"editor.tabSize" : 4
```

as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I solved removing the `.editorconfig`

Comment: Thanks - this helped me!

Comment: same; not sure how it was reduced to 0...alas this was the issue

Comment: In my case I needed to edit `.editorconfig` which was overriding tab width.

Answer (score 69):

You can try the following to change indentation/tab width:

**1.** At the bottom of your Editor window, check for the 'Spaces: 2' (in case your code is getting indented with 2 spaces). Click on that and choose Indent using Tab and choose the value according to your need.

[image: Image of the bottom section for your reference]

**2. Alter Prettier options in Visual Studio Code settings:** Go to the Visual Studio Code Setting by **`File > Preferences > Settings`** or pressing **`Ctrl + ,`**. Type '**Prettier**' to bring up all the settings related to Prettier and look for **Prettier: Tab Width**. Change the value according to your need.

**3. settings.json / User Settings file**: Add the following lines to **settings.json** file which contains all the configurations associated with VS Code.

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true,
```

Depending on your platform, the user settings file / settings.json is located here:

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

visit https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings for more info regarding User settings file / settings.json

**4. If you have `.editorconfig` file:** Check if you have a file named `.editorconfig` in the root of your project directory. In case you have that file, open it and make sure you change the values in the file according to your need. The below given code is for setting the **`indent_style` Tab** and the **`indent_size` 4**:

```
indent_style = tabs
indent_size = 4
```

**5. If you do not have a `.editorconfig` file:** In case you do not have a `.editorconfig` file in the root of your project directory, you can create a file named `.prettierrc` and add the following to the file

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "requireConfig": false,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "semi": true
}
```

You can alter this based on your requirement

Comment: Already have every single one of these and it still doesn't work... This is a real good answer though, I've encountered this problem before and usually it's one of these.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have the same problem except I want 2 tabs. I have set tabs to 2 in every possible location I could find.

Comment: I have format on save turned on and nothing worked for me. Step 5 above finally worked for me... but there's a hitch.  I added the .prettierrc file. It still didn't work so I set "Settings > User > Prettier: Config Path" to the location of my .prettierrc file (/Users/me/projects/.prettierrc) It now formats correctly when I save!

Answer (score 16):

Just create **.prettierrc** named file at the root of your project and paste the code bellow

in **.prettierrc**

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "requireConfig": false,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "semi": true
}
```

you can find the git issue here : https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/344#issuecomment-360430551

Comment: This should be the default answer.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have an `.editorconfig` file, but I'm using VS Code and needed to add `"editor.tabSize": 4` to my user `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

This takes in order to control of the formatting for prettier:

**1. Project Level Prettier Config**

If you have something like `.prettierrc.js` or `.prettierrc.json` in your project. Then this will be treated from prettier

Note: this will replace your code editor setting like vscode default setting (the No.2 below)

you can add something like

```
{
  "semi": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false
}
```

**2. Vscode Editor Level Prettier Config**

If you do not have these files in No.1, then the editor level settings will be applied, e.g. vscode settings, you can edit something like below:

```
// --- other content
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following setting to my solution's `.vscode/settings.json`:

`"editor.detectIndentation": false`

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `.prettierrc` file because prettier's logs said, "

> Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS
> Code configuration will not be used"

I suppose you either use a local config file or you use VS Code's config, but not both, so far.

Comment: For programming alone or just testing something out this approach is okay. If you work in a team however, the use of a `.prettierrc` file is recommended as you can track it with git and it sets a consistent formatting standard for your whole team. Automatic checks are also able to lint your code base using prettier but require a `.prettierrc` file to know how to format it.

Answer (score 0):

For Prettier Extension:
Go to the extension - cog icon after uninstall button - choose Extension Settings and then Prettier: Tab width. Change the value and it's done!

Comment: I tried this. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `.prettierrc.js` setup with `module.export`. Switching to `.prettierrc.yaml` and converting it to YAML configuration fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to vs code settings.
Search `Prettier: Tab Width` then add a number of spaces, it should use per tab, like 2/4, etc.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkpt0.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was forked project, so i had to run `npm install` for the `pretteir` to get installed in the context of the project.