# How do I change VSCode to indent 4 spaces instead of default 2?

Tags: visual-studio-code, default-value, auto-indent, autoformatting

I have applied the below settings in VS Code to get 4 spaces indentation. 
But always when I open a new file, it switches back to 2 in the right-bottom corner.

If I click in the right-bottom corner and change the setting back to 4, 
VSCode will still change back to 2 and still apply it with the 2-space auto-indent. 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What vscode version are you running?

Comment: Version: 1.21.0

Comment: In Settings->Workspace->Extensions->Vetur: TabSize = 4 and Use Tabs = true.
See this answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54340064/6393500

Answer (score 149):

Bit of an late answer. But just got the same issue solved...

Multiple things are able to control this. It also has taken me quite a bit of experimentation to get it corrected. For me point 3 below was the final trick to make it work. Before that, I noticed the editor loading with 4, but jumping back to 2 spaces. Now it stays at 4.

Some things to check:

1: VS Code configuration (Settings & Workspace, you can set these for system wide configuration or just for the current Workspace):
Check whether you have set:

```
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

And language specific settings (optional):

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
},
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
}
```

2: Are there any Extensions that could influence the indentation -> people have reported JS-CSS-HTML to also configure the setting.

3: Is there a .editorconfig file in your workspace? If so, check the settings over there. Angular creates one for example and configures the indent_size:

```
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Most answers focussed point 1 which, but for me the last step was important to make VS Code work properly.

This Stack Overflow handles all of the above in different answers:
[Visual Studio Code: format is not using indent settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251820/visual-studio-code-format-is-not-using-indent-settings)

Comment: Thanks for the update. My problem was rather with all the Angular plugins installed that over-rode the config. I close this issue now.

Comment: I got hit with the `.editorconfig`, thanks for ending my wild goose chase

Comment: `.editorconfig` was the problem for me, specifically a global `~/.editorconfig` file that was being used in place of an absent on in a project.

Comment: Adding another extension [Markdown All in One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) that override tab indentation for markdown files. You'll need to configure the extension.

Answer (score 57):

I fixed it in the VisualStudio settings (1.31)

Go to: settings > workspace settings > Text editor

uncheck 'Detect Indentation' to stick to your default setting.

Then restart the application.

Comment: Needed restart, but solution works,

Answer (score 12):

In many cases, it is `Prettier` that causes this. In fact, it just ignores all settings listed in @Oskar's answer.

So it needs to be overridden explicitly:

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true
```

And then just go to your file and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, and the correct indentation should be applied.

See also [Prettier is not indenting as specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763503/prettier-is-not-indenting-as-specified).

Answer (score 5):

Slightly different from previous answers.  I had **one file with the wrong indentation for its type and I wanted to correct only that file**.

(If you must know:  this Python script started out as text file with some queries in it.  I got it from psql's `-E \d` echo look at the postgres schemas).

Anyway, **this file** was now a Python .py file, with a 2 spaces indentation.  Not something that should be fixed by modifying general vscode settings.

What I did:

- click on the bottom status bar spot that says `2 Spaces`
- choose `Convert Indentation to Tabs` on the dialog popup.  Now it says `Tab size 2`
- click on the status bar again where it says Tab size 2
- choose `Convert Indentation to Spaces`.  Now the dialog changes to propose indent size:  `2` is selected. Pick `4` instead or any size you want.
- Done

[image]

Basically there are different ways through this dialog, but if you get into tab mode and then switch back to space-based indentation, it will allow you to pick the number of spaces you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful; this extension **EditorConfig for VS Code** interferes with vscode tab and indentation settings. Its installed by default but it is a nightmare. Disable it will solve all your problems.

Comment: No, it's not installed by default in VS Code. You have to install it manually. No extension needed to parse .editorConfig with Visual Studio by the way.

Comment: For me the actual tabsize keeps resetting itself to 4 when editor gets a focus. Disabling this extension actually helps. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another problem I discovered with Python is that VS Code uses autopep8. No matter which setting I tweaked, VS Code seemed to ignore the 2 spaces setting. If you want 2 spaces instead of 4 - the fix is to add this to your `settings.json`.

```json
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--indent-size=2",
        "--ignore E121"
    ]
```

Btw you can see your autopep8 arguments by opening the command palette (⌘-shift-p on mac) and entering `>Python: Show Language Server Output` then switching to view the "Python" log.

This seems to be a common issue. See: [VS Code Python autopep8 does not honor 2 spaces hanging indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430470/vs-code-python-autopep8-does-not-honor-2-spaces-hanging-indentation)

Answer (score 0):

For those who tired to wait a customisation from Dart guys here is a solution: fork the dart_style, change to own needs and setup the replacement  to be used in VSCode. Instruction is [here](https://github.com/mkakabaev/dart_style)