# I am have an issue with javascript formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am have trouble getting formatting to work for javascript in Visual Studio Code. I am using the Preitter formatter for almost everything except python.  Here is my VSCode settings for some of the files.

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

And here is my .prettierrc file:

```
{
    "printWidth": 120,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

The css, html all format fine, specifically the tab with.  However my javascript files don't indent 4 spaces only 2.  VSCode's default tab with is also set to 4.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: @B001ᛦ There's even a tag for vscode-related questions...

Comment: @B001ᛦ VS Code most certainly falls into the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category specified by the [help/on-topic] as on-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Change VSCode To Indent 4 Spaces Instead Of Default 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167053/how-do-i-change-vscode-to-indent-4-spaces-instead-of-default-2)