# VS Code Python Tab always 4 spaces instead of set 2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing python scripts in VS Code. In the settings the
[tab size is set to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G03AX.png), [tabs are replaced with spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eXpQ.png).

If I write a smple code snippet with tab size 2, and format the document, the tab size will be formatted to 4. It does not matter if the detect indentation is on or off.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

After formatting: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLfz9.png)

Edit: I think, I have to set the autopop8 settings. But I cannot find the settings

Comment: Tab size needn't be the same size as indentation size

Comment: @psmears but the shown width is 4 and also 4 spaces are included.

Comment: I think, I have to set the autopop8 settings. But I cannot find the settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Change VSCode To Indent 4 Spaces Instead Of Default 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167053/how-do-i-change-vscode-to-indent-4-spaces-instead-of-default-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can 1) add the following code in the `settings.json` file or 2) use the settings interface, which updates `settings.json` automatically. The quotes preceding each code block are from VSCode's documentation.

> The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden
> // based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.

```
"editor.tabSize": 4,
```

> Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overridden based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.

```
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
```

> When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces` will be detected based on the file contents. Set to false to keep the values you've explicitly set, above.

```
"editor.detectIndentation": false`
```