# Formatting all files in a directory in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, vscode-extensions

Related:

[How do I Change VSCode To Indent 4 Spaces Instead Of Default 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167053/how-do-i-change-vscode-to-indent-4-spaces-instead-of-default-2)

Is there a way to format all src files in a project in vscode?

In:

[image]

the formatting is set by default to LF, but the environment (win) expects CRLF. This can be done by hand but is tedious.

Can vscode set the format to LF for all files (js, html)?

For js files, the `.eslintrc.js` config needed an extra rule:

```
  rules: {
     ...
    "linebreak-style": "windows",
  },
```

Comment: extension [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles)

Answer (score 1):

the question has already been answered: [How can I make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code, Unix-like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix/48693007#48693007)

You can also configure the EOL for that extension so new files will follow your preference. Under "Settings", type in the search bar: `@lang:language-name @id:files.eol` and then choose the "User" or "Workspace" tab. Example: for java it will be: `@lang:java @id:files.eol`

[java eol configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw5i3.png)

Comment: Managed to change LF to CRLF for js files in .eslintrc.js by adding `"linebreak-style": "windows",` to `rules`. `htmllintrc` also needs an `indent-style` rule