# Prettier not following the configuration for ruby on VSCode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, prettier

Here is my User/settings.json:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.fontFamily": "D2Coding",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx": "linux"
    },
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 250
}
```

The default formatter is set to use prettier and I do have ruby gem, nvm package and vscode extension for prettier installed properly.

I have tested with a local configuration (.prettierrc) which only has tabWidth:

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4
}
```

and it is working fine for the JavaScript as you can see the below.

**Before formatting JavaScript:**

[image]

**After formatting JavaScript:**

[image]

**Before formatting Ruby:**

[image]

**After formatting Ruby:**

[image]

The following is the output of Prettier which has nothing special.

```
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Formatting file:///home/user/test_project/main.js
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Using config file at '/home/user/test_project/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at /home/user/test_project/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "babel"
}
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/home/user/test_project/main.js",
  "parser": "babel",
  "tabWidth": 4
}
["INFO" - 9:37:22 PM] Formatting completed in 0.012ms.





["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] Formatting file:///home/user/test_project/main.rb
["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] Using config file at '/home/user/test_project/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at /home/user/test_project/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "ruby"
}
["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 9:39:02 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/home/user/test_project/main.rb",
  "parser": "ruby",
  "tabWidth": 4
}
["INFO" - 9:39:03 PM] Formatting completed in 0.036ms.
```

Am I missing something at some point?

I literally tried every solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763503/prettier-is-not-indenting-as-specified), but no luck :/

Comment: Do you have the Ruby language server extension for VSCode?

Comment: @DorinBotan, Currently using a Ruby Solargraph which also has both ruby gem and VS Code extension installed!